# Escaping php '#' comment symbol in mysql database when exporting to csv

Tags: php, mysql, database, export-to-csv

I have a php script that exports a mysql database table to a csv file. For one of the fields of data, a user included an octothorp `#` in their text. For example, `My Idea #1`.

When my code gets to this piece of data, it stops at the `#` symbol. I'm guessing it hits the `#` and believes everything else that follows is a comment.

As a temporary solution, I am stripping out this symbol when adding the data to the database, but this is not ideal. Given the script below, how might I escape this symbol to prevent this from happening?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

    $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if (!$result) {
      die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
    }

    $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
    $headers = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
      $field = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i);
      // var_dump($field);
      $headers[] = $field->name;
    }

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    if ($fp && $result) {
      header('Content-Type: text/csv');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
      header('Pragma: no-cache');
      header('Expires: 0');
      fputcsv($fp, $headers);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
      }
      die;
    }
```

Comment: Try using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or `htmlspecialchars()` and if that doesn't solve the issue, you can always `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` it with an HTML entity.

Comment: can you tell us what the error you got?

Comment: @LeonKunštek I am using `mysqli_real_escape_string` for the data before is goes into the database, but this doesn't seem to handle the `#` as I don't think it has significance in SQL. It just causes issue back in my PHP script. I suppose I could encode these symbols when I put them in the database and decode them when they come out. Just initially seemed like unnecessary processing should a simpler solution exist.

Comment: @ChuckTaylor Do you just need to display the data on a webpage or does it have a function in the code later on?

Comment: @LeonKunštek No, it is not displaying on a webpage. It is just exporting the table to csv.

Comment: @ChuckTaylor When you get data from the database, you get it in the form of `strings` (a.k.a plain text) that shouldn't affect the code so there's a problem somewhere else. Could you enable php's error reporting and post the errors here?

Comment: @LeonKunštek I've enabled error reporting, but I am not receiving any. To help troubleshoot, I tried dumping the problem row to a textfile with `print_r` using `file_put_contents` in the same while loop as `fputcsv` And see it export fine

`Array
(
    [0] => 6584
    [1] => 2020-01-08 20:02:38
    [2] => Chuck#Test
    [3] => ximegas512@onmail.top
)`

The text file writes the entire database no problem, but the csv file is not seeing anything after the '#' as if the rest is commented. Because the text file is complete, the script is running to the end without error.